# django shell-plus: how to veiw a model definition from command line

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was using Django Rest Framework and I came across `repr()` function

When I do in the Django shell

```
>> from articles.api.serializers import PostSerializer
   print(repr(PostSerializer()))

PostSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    publish_date = DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC')
    is_deleted = BooleanField(required=False)
    title = CharField(max_length=256)
    intro_image = ImageField(allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)
    slug = SlugField(max_length=50)
    task_id = CharField(read_only=True)
    qa_bool = BooleanField(label='Allow Q&A', required=False)
```

Assume i have model Article. I have tried:

```
>> print(repr(Article))

<class 'articles.models.Article'>
```

I want to see all the fields with their properties from shell. Is it possible

Comment: As far as I know, this is a feature of DRF, not Django itself. In theory, you could create a generic Model template with `__repr__()` method and then inherit from this template across your app, but it seems like a stretch to me. Another way would be to have an external helper that takes model as a parameter and outputs the fields. Or maybe wait until Django supports this natively (I don't know if they plan to do so.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's `_meta` Api like so:

```
>>> Article._meta.get_fields()
<<< { tuple with all fields and types }
```